# Should I close-vote AND flag?

Tags: support, flagging, vote-to-close

I've recently gained enough privilege to close-vote questions, but for the question to actually be closed it needs 5 votes in total, or a moderator to close it. It has already been noted that the lack of active members with this privilege mean that the chances of a 'bad' question reaching 5 down-votes is not particularly high. So in a bid to quicken the process, should I also flag it? Or would this be over-kill?

Comment: Same doubt here, but now answered :) . . . Found an old Q that I think is duplicate and had the doubt *"but this one is old, will anyone see my close vote?"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can close-vote, *please don't flag the question at the same time.*

Moderators have tools where we can see exactly which questions have been close-voted and can take action immediately with a binding decision if necessary.

Flagging questions for moderator attention is more a tool for users w/o the reputation to close-vote.  More of a last resort than anything else.

Answer (score 4):

I view close-flags as a stop-gap for users without close-vote privileges. Since flags must be acted on by moderators, I would  suggest that close-voting *and* flagging merely creates more work for the mods.

So, if you have close-vote privileges, just vote to close. *Don't* also flag.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others on this one. There is no need to flag on top of voting to close. But if you have close vote powers you cannot actually flag the question for the normal reasons. Once you have close vote powers you can only flag questions if its spam or it needs other moderator attention.